# How to strongly type fetch with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a custom fetch function which thanks to TypeScript has strongly type params and returns.

Imagine I declare types like this

```
interface ResponseData {
   status: 'success' | 'error';
}

interface RequestBody {
   foo: string;
   bar: number;
}

const endpoint = {
   url: '/endpointurl/',
   method: 'get',
   
   /* A way to associate RequestBody and ResponseData types */
};
```

I would like to call my custom fetch function with endpoint object and automatically have typing on the body I pass in params and the data I get in returns

```
/* myfetch would use endpoint.url and endpoint.method to fetch data */

const data = myfetch(endpoint, { foo: "hello", bar: 42 } /* body params MUST be of RequestBody type */ ); 

data.success; /* data is of type ResponseData */
```

Is there a way to achieve that with TypeScript?
And if not what would be your approach to have a similar behavior?

Comment: You have a common but fundamental misconception: compilers type check by *proving* that a variable is a certain type of value and can never be anything else (or throwing an error if they can't). It is not *logically* possible to prove this at compile time something being deserialized from over the wire. You will have to check that the fetched values conform to whatever schema you have *at runtime*. You can use a schema validator like [zod](https://zod.dev/) to generate the checks and type predicates for you, but you can't just slap a generic on there and call it a day.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the reply ! I understand I cannot check data validity at runtime, what I would like is enforcing typing in my app by associates a type to an url, so the caller cannot call this endpoint without dealing with this type of data. Once again I am not talking at runtime.

Comment: "I understand I cannot check data validity at runtime" yes you can, and in fact must. What you cannot do is check the data validity *at compile time*. "mapping associates a type to an url" that's what I'm saying, there's **no way** to make that type-safe, your suggestion is not any more safe than just casting. The **only** thing you can do is validate the data at runtime.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain myself well.
I mean I understand I can't do that with Typescript, I know about zod and other type checker.
What I am trying to acheive is sharing my type between back and front, and so I would like to strongly types I expect based on url in order to ease my dev work

Comment: That's how GitHub's `@octokit` packages work, return types are based on the endpoint argument: https://github.com/octokit/types.ts/tree/main#get-parameter-and-response-data-types-for-a-rest-api-endpoint. Simplest starting point would just be function overloads.

Comment: @damjuve you probably want something like [tRPC](https://trpc.io/) (or possible graphQL) then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it gets you all the way you want to be, but you could implement typeguards and pass them as part of your interface object which would provide run-time protection.

For the compile-time validation you could use a generic function and specify the request/response as part of the call. That could also be wrapped in a factory to return specific functions on demand.

Something like the below... (I confess I didn't compile this, but should give you the idea)

```
interface ResponseData {
   status: 'success' | 'error';
}

function responseDataGuard(x: any): x is ResponseData {
  return x.status === 'success' || x.status === 'error';
}

interface RequestBody {
   foo: string;
   bar: number;
}

function requestBodyGuard(x: any): x is RequestBody {
  return typeof foo === 'string' && typeof bar === 'number';
}

interface EndPoint {
   url: string;
   method: 'get' | 'post';
   responseDataGuard: () => boolean;
   requestBodyGuard: () => boolean;
}

const endpoint = {
   url: '/endpointurl/',
   method: 'get',
   requestBodyGuard: requestBodyGuard,
   responseDataGuard: responseDataGuard
};

async function myfetch<ReqBodyType, ResDataType>(endpoint: EndPoint, body: ReqBodyType): Promise<ResDataType> {
  // Not entirely sure this is necessary, as the Typing would protect.
  if (!endpoint.requestBodyGuard(req)) {
    throw new Error('invalid request body');
  }
  const response = await doRealHttpFetch(endpoint.url, body); 
  // But we do need to validate the response if we are to trust it, and typescript is accept it as being of the return type
  if (!endpoint.responseDataGuard(response)) {
    throw new Error('invalid response type');
  }
  return response;
}

const data = await myfetch<ResponseData, RequestBody>(endpoint, { foo: "hello", bar: 42 } ); 

// This is code driven, not data driven but does put all the api
// definition in one config driven place; returning an function
// based on the key for the api provided. That said I suspect the 
// Typings are lost by the factory, which might defeat your purpose

function fetchFactory(key: string): (any) => Promise<any> {

  const endpoints = {
    api1: {
      url: '/endpointurl/',
      method: 'get',
      requestBodyGuard: requestBodyGuard,
      responseDataGuard: responseDataGuard
    }
  };

  switch(key) {
     case 'api1': return (data: RequestBody) => myfetch<ResponseData, RequestBody>( endpoints[key] , data );
     default: throw new Error('unknown key');
  }

}

const mySpecificFetch = fetchFactory('api1');
const data = await mySpecificFetch({ foo: "hello", bar: 42 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your awnser, I finally found a first way to implement what I want :

```
enum RouteNames {
  Route1 = "route1",
  Route2 = "route2",
  Route3 = "route3"
}

type RouteList = {
  [key in RouteNames]: {
    response: unknown;
    payload: unknown;
  };
};

interface Routes extends RouteList {
  [RouteNames.Route1]: { 
    response: {
      foo: string
    };
    payload: {
      bar: number;
    }
  };
  [RouteNames.Route2]: { 
    response: {
      hello: string
    };
    payload: {
      world: string;
    }
  }
}

type RouteValues = {
  [key in RouteNames]: {
    url: string;
    method: 'get' | 'post'
  }
}

const routeValues: RouteValues = {
  [RouteNames.Route1]: {
    url: '/route1',
    method: 'get'
  },
  [RouteNames.Route2]: {
    url: '/route2',
    method: 'post',
  },
  [RouteNames.Route3]: {
    url: '/route3',
    method: 'get'
  }
}

async function myFetch<Route extends RouteNames>(route: Route, options?: {payload?: Routes[Route]["payload"]}): Promise<Routes[Route]["response"]> {
  const data = await fetch(routeValues[route].url, {method: routeValues[route].method, body: options?.payload ? JSON.stringify(options.payload) : undefined});
  return await data.json() as Routes[Route]["response"];  
}

async function test() {
  const data1 = await myFetch(RouteNames.Route1, {payload: {bar: 42}}); // data1 has type { foo: string }
  const data2 = await myFetch(RouteNames.Route2, {payload: {bar: 42}}); // Error on { bar: 42 }
  const data3 = await myFetch(RouteNames.Route3); // data3 is unknown
  const data10 = await myFetch(RouteNames.Route1, {}); // data1 has type { foo: string }

}
```

The only thing still not working is the payload type.
If I type it wrongly I got a typescript error but two case still not working as I would like :

- if I omit it while it is required I dont get error
- if I put a payload while there is no expected I got no error

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript only exists in the **source** code but you'd like to use types based on the data you receive at **runtime** which is impossible.

The best thing you can do is **assert** the body type with TypeScript, so that your code is consistent with itself, but there can be no guarantee that the actual body respects its type when the code runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I understand I cannot check data validity at runtime, what I would like is enforcing typing in my app by associates a type to an url, so the caller cannot call this endpoint without dealing with this type of data. Once again I am not talking at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Only with Typescript, no.

With [Remix](https://remix.run/) and [remix-typedjson](https://github.com/kiliman/remix-typedjson), yes. Typedjson offers a hook called `useTypedFetcher`, which you can use along with Remix resource routes, to derive the output type of the route. Type-hinting works properly on successful resource route calls.

Comment: You could also use something like [tRPC](https://trpc.io/) to achieve the same effect without Remix. Which doesn't mean much if you don't have a node.js backend...